# How to write a new image and zero pad reference image on that new image in C

Tags: c, image-processing

I have an image of size M*N, now I need to create a new image of size P*Q where P=2M-1 and Q=2N-1

[image]

Here, f(x,y) is my reference image, and have to place as shown in the figure.

Here's my function of writing to new image

```
void WritePGM(FILE* fp)
{
    int i, j;
    int p, q;
    p = 2*m-1;
    q = 2*n-1;  
    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%d %d\n%d\n", p, q, 255);

    for (j = 0; j<n; j++)

        for (i = 0; i<m; i++) {
            fputc(image1[m,n], fp);
        }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Can you suggest me the way I should rewrite the loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong:

1. `[m,n]` isn't valid C code.
2. `[m][n]` *is* but this only writes the bottom right pixel to all output.
3. Your loops are doing a transpose (I think--most images are `matrix[YDIM][XDIM]`).

You *can* do this with *one* set of nested loops, but it's easier with two. Here is something close to what I think you want [I haven't tested it]. It assumes you want it output in video scan line order (i.e. `j` is the Y dimension and `i` is the X dimension):

```
void
WritePGM(FILE * fp)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int p;
    int q;

    p = 2 * m - 1;
    q = 2 * n - 1;

    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%d %d\n%d\n", p, q, 255);

    j = 0;

    // write top half of image
    for (; j < n; j++) {
        i = 0;

        // output left half of scan line
        for (; i < m; i++)
            fputc(image1[j][i], fp);

        // output right half of scan line (zeroes)
        for (; i < p; i++)
            fputc(0, fp);
    }

    // write bottom half of image (zeroes)
    for (; j < q; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            fputc(0, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

---

> While writing `image1[j][i]` it gives error: *[Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector*. `image1` is defined globally as `unsigned char *image1;`

It's easy to change to a one dimensional array. Also, most video images (i.e. still images like `.png`, `.jpg`, etc.) use the `y/x` nomenclature, so I'm switching to that:

```
void
WritePGM(FILE * fp)
{
    int xcur;
    int ycur;
    int xmax2;
    int ymax2;
    unsigned char *scanline;

    xmax2 = 2 * xmax - 1;
    ymax2 = 2 * ymax - 1;

    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%d %d\n%d\n", xmax2, ymax2, 255);

    ycur = 0;

    // write top half of image
    for (; ycur < ymax; ycur++) {
        scanline = image1 + (ycur * xmax);

        xcur = 0;

        // output left half of scan line
        for (; xcur < xmax; xcur++)
            fputc(scanline[xcur], fp);

        // output right half of scan line (zeroes)
        for (; xcur < xmax2; xcur++)
            fputc(0, fp);
    }

    // write bottom half of image (zeroes)
    for (; ycur < ymax2; ycur++) {
        for (i = 0; i < xmax2; xcur++)
            fputc(0, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

The above should work. Here is the equivalent done a bit faster:

```
void
WritePGM(FILE * fp)
{
    int ycur;
    int xmax2;
    int ymax2;
    unsigned char *scanline;

    xmax2 = 2 * xmax - 1;
    ymax2 = 2 * ymax - 1;

    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%d %d\n%d\n", xmax2, ymax2, 255);

    unsigned char zeroline[xmax2];

    memset(zeroline,0,sizeof(zeroline));

    ycur = 0;

    // write top half of image
    for (; ycur < ymax; ycur++) {
        scanline = image1 + (ycur * xmax);

        // output left half of scan line
        fwrite(scanline,1,xmax,fp);

        // output right half of scan line (zeroes)
        fwrite(zeroline,1,xmax2 - xmax,fp);
    }

    // write bottom half of image (zeroes)
    for (; ycur < ymax2; ycur++)
        fwrite(zeroline,1,xmax2,fp);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: While writing `image1[j][i]` it gives error `[Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`, `image1` is defined globally as `unsigned char *image1;`

Comment: Okay, that I can fix: to use a one dimensional array easily enough. Can you confirm the [pseudo] 2D format: `char image1[ymax][xmax]`? (i.e. `ymax` is `n` and `xmax` is `m`)